# Difference between class constant and class static variable with array as a value in php7?

Tags: php, php-7, oop

Example:

```
class Test
    {
        const URLS = [
            'http://example.com/',
            'http://example1.com/'
        ];

        public static $urls = [
            'http://example.com/',
            'http://example1.com/'
        ];
    }
```

Whats difference in the above `$urls` and `URLS` w.r.t PHP7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the static variable values. See Example Below

```
print_r(Test::$urls); // Array ( [0] => http://example.com/ [1] => http://example1.com/ )
print_r(Test::URLS); // Array ( [0] => http://example.com/ [1] => http://example1.com/ )
Test::$urls = [];
print_r(Test::$urls); // Array ( )
//Test::URLS = []; // Error
```

For more information Please refer to the link"
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1685933/5962966